# Would someone help me to revise the following extracts and make Pat's line sound The United States

Tags: phrase-usage

*PAT (улыбаясь)* : You Russians are weird. You are so much attached to the past. I mean that story about a small boy in a woolen aviator’s cap… It’s fatal to keep living in the past for so long while. Lifetime is too short to be suffering non-stop, isn’t it?

*POLINA* : It’s… I’m definitely going to live in the present, but I always fail to make out where is it? What do people call the present?

*PAT* (Улыбаясь) : Look, the present is what is going on now. We are looking at each other, drinking, talking, walking, whatsoever.

*POLINA* : True.

*PAT* : Shakespeare, Blake, Rilke…Isn’t all they did living nowadays?

*POLINA* : Stop talking to me shrink-like! I remember staying on upper desk while the liner was putting away to Europe feeling so happy…I hoped here in Europe I would recall something wonderful unfairly lost… But now I am missing home again.

*PAT* : Close your eyes, please...

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking. Are you saying rewrite Pat's lines to make it sound like he is from The United States? I'm not sure that is considered on topic, because it's not directly related to learning the English Language. http://ell.stackexchange.com/tour

Comment: Sorry, we don't really do proofreading here unless there's a specific issue related to the English Language that you're trying to figure out.

Comment: Thanks for your prompt reply. Yes I mean rewriting Pat's line this way. I am sorry if it all goes beyond restrictions but may it be considered related to learning English indirectly?

Comment: Well, I'm always happy to rewrite anything to sound like a middle-class professional from the US. Offer extended.

Comment: gerol - If you phrase the question so that it is more related to learning English, you'll have better chances of success. In this instance, your title screams, "Would someone help me revise this?" That's a proofreading request. Instead, try, "I'm writing (or translating) a play, and I want to know if these lines sound the way people speak naturally in the US." (That _still_ might get closed as proofreading, but I think more people would try to help with a question like that, and the close votes might be slowed some.) It might also help if you provided two wordings, and asked which was better.

Comment: (cont.) If one or two questions are asked, that might be okay, but if we wind up reading this entire play line by line, scene by scene, that will wear on the community quite quickly, and will be stopped. But if you ask, for example, "I'm trying to say that the writing of Shakespeare is still 'alive' nowadays - is this a good way to say it?" that would be more a general English question, and less of a _let's-all-co-author-this-play-together_ question.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your being so helpful! ) No doubt, next time I will follow your advice.

Answer (score 1):

You Russians are weird. You are so attached to the past. I mean, look at that story about a small boy in a woolen aviator’s cap… You can't keep living in the past all the time. Life is too short to be suffering non-stop, isn’t it?

Look, the present is what's happening now. We are looking at each other, drinking, talking, walking, whatever.

Shakespeare, Blake, Rilke…isn’t everything they wrote still living now?  *(I'm not at all sure that this is what you mean, but it might be.)*

I'll leave Polina's stuff the way it is because it makes her sound like she has a Russian accent, far better than I could do it!  :)  However, *upper desk* should be *upper deck*.

Comment: Thank you very much Bob Rodes, for your help. Of course, deck!!! Just miswriting. I'm very pleased you've considered my request in depth.)

Comment: Of course.  This is more of a creative writing question, than a question of grammar.  That's why you're getting the negative feedback, since this isn't really a creative writing forum.  Maybe we should make one.  :)

Comment: ..............Some hope)

Comment: There _is_ a writing forum: [writers.se]; however, even Writers is [leery about proofreading](http://meta.writers.stackexchange.com/questions/301/should-we-allow-grammar-proofreading-questions). The main concern seems to be: once we start allowing proofreading, we'll be flooded with requests to proofread. (That said, Bob, I like your answer here.)

Answer (score 0):

PAT (улыбаясь) : You Russians are weird. You're so attached to the past. I mean, that story about a small boy in a woolen aviator’s cap… it’s fatal [pathological | dangerous | not healthy] to keep living in the past. Life's too short to suffer non-stop, isn’t it?

POLINA : It’s… I’m definitely going to live in the present, but I always fail to make out where is it? What do people call the present?

PAT (Улыбаясь) : Look, the present is what is going on now. We're looking at each other, drinking, talking, walking, whatever.

POLINA : True.

PAT : Shakespeare, Blake, Rilke... didn't they simply LIVE?

POLINA : Stop talking to me shrink-like! I remember staying on upper desk while the liner was putting away to Europe feeling so happy…I hoped here in Europe I would recall something wonderful unfairly lost… But now I am missing home again.

PAT : Close your eyes...